# Why EF Core generates inverted bit comparison

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-5

We are trying to upgrade our project to .net core 5. And now we're struggling with a strange EF behaviour.
A simple query:

```cs
context.Set<Order>().Where(o => o.Archived == false)
```

where *Order.Archived* is bit NOT NULL in the database, generates such a query:

```sql
select * from Order where Archived <> CAST(1 as bit)
```

Why does this happen? We are expecting to have query like the following instead:

```sql
select * from Order where Archived = CAST(0 as bit)
```

Such inversion may prevent proper indices from being used by the database in more complex queries.
Is there a way to make EF generate a more straightforward query?

P.S.: We also tried this same approach with nullable fields. And there we do receive the expected query.

Comment: "Such inversion may prevent proper indeces from being used ...  in more complex queries" - so is there actually a problem being caused right now by this specific translation?

Comment: So, create issue in github.

Comment: What does `o => !o.Archived` yield? If this doesn't work because `Archived` is nullable (even though it's not nullable in the DB) your model might need tweaking.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Archived is not nullable in model and in database as well. o => !o.Archived yields the same strange query.

Comment: @AakashM yes, there is an issue with this.

Comment: Are you going to tell us it?

Comment: @AakashM it is just what is said in the OP. The production query is different, but the problem with both of the queries is the same.

Answer (score 2):

I looked into this and for nullable properties it works well, as expected.
For non-nullable properties I found this trick, which gives expected result

```
context.Set<Order>().Where(o => new []{false}.Contains(o.Archived))
```

In that case we receive following sql query:

```
select * from Order where Archived = CAST(0 as bit)
```